# Вращение объекта Jcomponent

Tags: java, swing

Есть объект Jlabel внутри него находится изображение, как реализовать поворот компонента JLabel.
На данный момент могу поворачивать чисто картинку, которая не находится в jlabel вот код:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
    super.paintComponent(gr);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;

    g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

    int cx = GameMenu.BLOCK_WEIGHT/ 3;
    int cy = GameMenu.BLOCK_HIEGHT/ 2;
    AffineTransform oldAT = g.getTransform();
    g.translate(cx+imagePosition.x, cy+imagePosition.y);
    g.rotate(imageAngleRad);
    g.translate(-cx, -cy);
    g.drawImage(scaled, 0, 0, null);
    g.setTransform(oldAT);

}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    mousePoint = e.getPoint();
    double dx = e.getX() - imagePosition.getX();
    double dy = e.getY() - imagePosition.getY();
    imageAngleRad = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    repaint();
}
```

scale - это изображение в ByfferedImage;
Весь интернет перерыл ничего не могу найти! Кто может, помогите пожалуйста!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зелёный тот который вращается за мышкой, он не находится в Jlabel, а красный который двигается как требуется , но не может вращаться так как он в Jlabel.

Comment: так не получится, придется вращать содержимое...

Comment: Можете прояснить пожалуйста?

Comment: ну нет в swing возможности повернуть компонент

Comment: А как вращать содержимое и как это будет выглядеть?

Comment: я оформлю ответ, как доберусь до компа, а пока по подробнее опишите что Вы рисуете, или макет картинкудобавьте

Comment: В кратце это мини шутер, в jlabe находится персонаж, я его добавил в jlabel для нормальной реализации передвижения. Мне главное понять принцип как вообще вращать его, а дальше я уже смогу и сам допилить. Вот этот код прекрасно работал когда я не использовал компонент, но без компонента, у меня были проблемы с перемещентем(была задержка из-за keylistner,  пришлось использовать keybilding, с использование inputmap и actionmap)

Comment: я бы нарисовал все на одной панели

Comment: Сможете кинуть пример?

Comment: слегка погодя, его придется сперва собрать

Comment: Хорошо, мне не к спеху)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо не вращать компоненты, а нарисовать все на одном компоненте.

Вот собрал пример c несколькими поворачивающимися объектами на одной канве:

Управление - `WSAD` (повороты и движение)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Game extends JLabel  {

    Player player;

    static RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    long time = 0;

    List<Tank> vehicles = new ArrayList<Tank>(){{
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            add(new Tank());
        }
    }};

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        tick();
        draw((Graphics2D) g);
    }

    private void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setRenderingHints(rh);
        g.clearRect(0,0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        // так будет (0,0) по центру
        g.translate(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
        for (Tank t: vehicles) {
            t.drawTank((Graphics2D) g.create());
        }
        g.translate(-getWidth()/2, -getHeight()/2);
    }

    private void tick() {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        float dt = (millis - time) / 300f;
        for (Tank t : vehicles) {
            t.tick(dt);
        }
        this.time = millis;
    }

    Game(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
        this.vehicles.add(player);
        this.time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        new Timer(20, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }
        }).start();
        new Timer(1, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tick();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Player player = new Player();
        frame.add(new Game(player));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addKeyListener(player);
    }
}
```

---

```
class Action {
    boolean pressed;
    float speed;
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Player extends Tank implements KeyListener {

    public Player() {
        x=0;
        y=0;
        r=0;
    }

    Map<Integer, Action> actions = new HashMap<Integer, Action>(){{
        put(KeyEvent.VK_W, new Action());
        put(KeyEvent.VK_S, new Action());
        put(KeyEvent.VK_A, new Action());
        put(KeyEvent.VK_D, new Action());
    }};

    public void tick(float dt) {
        for (Integer key : actions.keySet()) {
            Action action = actions.get(key);

            if (action.pressed) {
                action.speed = Math.min(action.speed + dt, 0.5f);
            } else {
                if (action.speed > 0) {
                    action.speed = Math.max(action.speed - dt, 0);
                }
            }

            float dir = key == KeyEvent.VK_W || key == KeyEvent.VK_D ? 1 : -1;
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W || key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                y += Math.sin(r) * action.speed * dir;
                x += Math.cos(r) * action.speed * dir;
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A || key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                r += action.speed / 100 * dir;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        act(e, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        act(e, false);
    }

    void act(KeyEvent e, boolean state){
        Action action = actions.get(e.getKeyCode());
        if (null != action)
            action.pressed = state;
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Tank {

    int w = 40;
    int h = 40;

    protected double x = (Math.random()-0.5)*400;
    protected double y =  (Math.random()-0.5)*400;
    protected double r =  Math.random()*360;

    public void drawTank(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.translate(x , y);
        g2d.rotate(r);
        g2d.translate(-w/2, -h/2);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        g2d.translate(w/2, h/2);
        g2d.fillRect(0, -3, w, 6);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    public void tick(float dt) {
        r+=dt/100.;
    }
}
```

---

Comment: @WolFRam я не стал писать комментарии в коде, если есть вопросы - спрашивайте тут, а я дополню код комментами

Comment: Я чуток другое имел ввиду) То есть я иду могу ходить прямо, назад вперёд, влево, вправо и по диагонали( это у меня есть). Чтобы герой вращался в том направлении куда смотрит игрок)

Comment: @WolFRam можно попросить Вас приложить скрин того что есть и дорисовать на нем как то что надо

Comment: Добавил в исходное

Comment: @WolFRam кажется я понял, я свои танки на такой же манер управления переделаю, только вечерком, кстати уже нашел там ошибку у себя =] метод tick не надо вызывать в paintComponent, я для него таймер создал отдельный, хотя визуально вряд ли что то изменится

Comment: Хорошо буду ждать)

Comment: @WolFRam тут есть один важный момент, необходимо отделять игровую логику от логики отрисовки, и я пытался тут так сделать. время идет отдельно и состояние меняется там, а второй таймер вызывает отрисовку всех объектов сцены в цикле

Answer (score 0):

Вот собрал второй вариант, не стал добавлять в старый ответ т.к. много кода.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
class Action {
    boolean pressed;
    float speed;
}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Game extends JLabel  {

    Player player;

    static RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    long time = 0;

    List<Tank> vehicles = new ArrayList<Tank>(){{
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            add(new Tank());
        }
    }};

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        draw((Graphics2D) g);
    }

    private void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setRenderingHints(rh);
        g.clearRect(0,0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        // так будет (0,0) по центру
        g.translate(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
        for (Tank t: vehicles) {
            t.drawTank((Graphics2D) g.create());
        }
        g.translate(-getWidth()/2, -getHeight()/2);
    }

    private void tick() {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        float dt = (millis - time) / 300f;
        for (Tank t : vehicles) {
            t.tick(dt, player.x, player.y);
        }
        this.time = millis;
    }

    Game(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
        this.vehicles.add(player);
        this.time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        new Timer(20, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }
        }).start();
        new Timer(1, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tick();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        final Player player = new Player();
        final Game game = new Game(player);

        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                player.move(e, true);
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                player.move(e, false);
            }
        });
        game.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                player.rotate(e.getX() - game.getWidth()/2, e.getY() - game.getHeight()/2);
            }
        });

        frame.add(game);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Player extends Tank {


    private int my;
    private int mx;

    public Player() {
        x=0;
        y=0;
        r=0;
    }

    Map<Integer, Action> actions = new HashMap<Integer, Action>(){{
        put(KeyEvent.VK_W, new Action());
        put(KeyEvent.VK_S, new Action());
        put(KeyEvent.VK_A, new Action());
        put(KeyEvent.VK_D, new Action());
    }};

    @Override
    public void tick(float dt, double x1, double y1) {
        for (Integer key : actions.keySet()) {
            Action action = actions.get(key);

            if (action.pressed) {
                action.speed = Math.min(action.speed + dt, 0.5f);
            } else {
                if (action.speed > 0) {
                    action.speed = Math.max(action.speed - dt, 0);
                }
            }

            float dir = key == KeyEvent.VK_W || key == KeyEvent.VK_D ? 1 : -1;
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W || key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                y += Math.sin(r) * action.speed * dir;
                x += Math.cos(r) * action.speed * dir;
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A || key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                y += Math.sin(r+Math.PI/2) * action.speed * dir;
                x += Math.cos(r+Math.PI/2) * action.speed * dir;
            }
        }
        r = Math.PI + Math.atan2(this.y - my, this.x - mx);

    }

    public void move(KeyEvent e, boolean state){
        Action action = actions.get(e.getKeyCode());
        if (null != action)
            action.pressed = state;
    }


    public void rotate(int x, int y) {
        r = Math.PI + Math.atan2(this.y - (my = y), this.x - (mx = x));
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Tank {

    int w = 40;
    int h = 40;

    public double x = (Math.random()-0.5)*400;
    public double y =  (Math.random()-0.5)*400;
    public double r =  Math.random()*360;

    public void drawTank(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.translate(x , y);
        g2d.rotate(r);
        g2d.translate(-w/2, -h/2);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        g2d.translate(w/2, h/2);
        g2d.fillRect(0, -3, w, 6);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    public void tick(float dt, double x, double y) {
        r = Math.PI + Math.atan2(this.y -  y, this.x - x);
    }
}
```